# How do you change the formated font color of a cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select rows in my excel sheet based on a criteria and then edit the format of other cells in the same row.

I know that I can select rows using autofilters (column n equals ""):

```
Sub beautify()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("F60:AJ3272")
rng.AutoFilter Field:=4, Field:=4, Criteria1:=""

End Sub
```

Now how do I change the font of column F of the lines that I have selected to white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VBA to change the background color of a cell using `.Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(r, g, b) : red` and the font color of the text inside a cell with `.Font.Color = RGB(r, g, b) : red`
The range to change these property on should be defined, like mentionned in your question by the column and the row you selected so say you chose column F and row 12 it should look like this:

```
Range("F12").Font.Color = -4142
```

So say you want to scroll through every row of a column, and change the color of every blank cell what you could do is :

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Rows.Count
'Column F is 6
If Cells(i, 6).Value = "" Then
  Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(150, 0, 0)
Next i
```

Comment: How can I make this work together with my autofilter? If I enter rng2=rng.AutoFilter Field:=4, Field:=4, Criteria1:="" I am getting an error

Comment: I would recomend you to simply scroll through all your rows instead of using a static range. This way you can isolate a cell to modify

Comment: Could you give an example? I only would like to color the rows that are blank in coloumn F (and thus would like to automatize the process)

Comment: I edited my answer to show you an example of an approach you could take

Answer (score 0):

I made slight modifications to your code and it worked:

```
Sub beautify()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 50
 If Cells(i, 9).Value = "" Then
  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i, 31)).Font.Color = vbBlack
  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, 8)).Font.Color = vbWhite
 End If

Next i

End Sub
```